# AWS Elastic Beanstalk cli check for instances existing key pairs

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, key-pair

I want to make some order on servers under the Beanstalk environments
In our organization.
Some are set to use key pair and some are not
I thought of using aws cli or eb cli
To sample all the servers and return wether or not a key pair exist
And if so what it’s value.

I would be happy to to hear any recommendations on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query \
"Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,KeyName,State.Name]"
```

This will return the list of all instances along with their key-pair (if it exists) and the state of the instance

```
[
    [
        "i-07a25c4ae7e6abxxx",
        "MyEC2KeyPair",
        "stopped"
    ],
    [
        "i-0c76af91e45018xxx",
        null,
        "pending"
    ],
    [
        "i-05acb0a0be3d21xxx",
        "MyEC2KeyPair",
        "shutting-down"
    ]
]
```

Note, this has to be run for each region; so if you want to run it for all available ec2 region, you can run the following query

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --query "Regions[].[RegionName]" --output text \
| xargs -I {} aws ec2 describe-instances \ 
    --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Placement.AvailabilityZone,InstanceId,KeyName,State.Name]" \
    --region {}
```

This will list all instances per region and display the Availability Zone.